# How to line up tables in excel using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to align two tables in Excel using a VBA.

Basically I have:

```
 Table 1                 Table 2              
7 columns               7 columns
```

In table 2, some of the rows are missing from Table 1!

I used this VBA below but it didn't work because in my tables I have got 7 columns for both. I need to make sure both 7 columns for both tables match even if some rows are missing in my second table.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Set rng1 = Range([a1], Cells(Columns.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    rng1.Offset(0, 1).Columns.Insert
    With rng1.Offset(0, 1)
        .FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(ISNA(MATCH(RC[-1],C[1],0)),"""",INDEX(C[1],MATCH(RC[-1],C[1],0)))"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Any ideas anyone, I would attach a picture but this my first time using Stackoverflow lol !

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show a simple set of data (as text) before and after Table 2 is fixed?

Comment: @PeterM Anyway I can add a picture? because its much easier if I could show you !

Comment: Example are in the links http://imageshack.com/a/img540/6440/sTJOq9.jpg
http://imageshack.com/a/img661/6121/c2aLle.jpg @PeterM

Comment: @NanaWoahene your uploads are not working. Try using dropbox.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b1menptbcfm7fs7/a0c74833c8361438f76d573b905b995b.jpg?dl=0

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lag1yyfarqcbnp1/00257c370f060c2768160a03325cbd52.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Not exactly getting the aligning requirement? column data are same for both area? In both area, 6 columns are adjacent and 1 column is away. your output should be: adjacent 7 columns for 1st area + extra rows for 2nd area appended below the 1st area?

Comment: Okay if you look at the picture named doesn't match.

Comment: Okay if you look at the picture named doesn't match.

Comment: The table on the left has all the correct items. Whilst the table on the right is missing "vehicle repairs" row. I want a row to be added so they both match. Make sense?

Comment: This is your question so you are informed if a comment or answer is posted against it.  The poster of the comment is only told you have replied if you include @UserName in the reply.

Comment: In your picture both tables are in the same worksheet and the rows are in line until a row is missed from table 2.  Is this true of the real problem.

Comment: Yes its true @tonydallimore

Answer (score 1):

Although this answer does include some code, it is more concerned with teaching you how to write a similar macro yourself.

I should say now that I do not approve of my code:

- My macro does not check table 2.  If table 2 contains a row that is not present in table 1, my macro will move that row, and any below it, down leaving a very large gap.
- It is bad practice to update data like this in situ.  If anything goes wrong, the data will have been partially changed. You will probably have to start again with a backup of the original workbook. It is better to create a new worksheet and to copy the data as necessary to create the appearance you seek.

You have code to find the last row of a worksheet but the following is simpler and just as reliable:

```
With Worksheets("Data")
  RowExistLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, ColExistId).End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

It is rarely a good idea to operate on the active worksheet.  For example, if the user starts the macro with the wrong worksheet active, that worksheet will be corrupted. My code will operate on the specified worksheet even if it is not active.

You need to examine every row in table 1. The code below outputs the contents of the Id column of every row of table 1 to the Immediate window.  If you ran this code, all but the last 200 or so rows will have scrolled off the top of the window:

```
  With Worksheets("Data")
    RowExistLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, ColExistId).End(xlUp).Row
    For RowExistCrnt = RowDataFirst To RowExistLast
      Debug.Print .Cells(RowExistCrnt, ColExistId).Value
    Next
  End With
```

I could not step down table 2 using a `For` loop. The end value of the loop cannot be changed within the loop but we will be inserting lines. A `Do While` loop would be necessary:

```
RowNewCrnt = RowDataFirst
Do While RowNewCrnt <= RowNewLast
  :
  ' If row inserted
  RowNewLast = RowNewLast + 1
  :
  ' With For loop, control variable is stepped automatically.
  ' With Do loop, you must step it as necessary.
  :
  RowNewCrnt = RowNewCrnt + 1
Next
```

Because I am trying to align the rows in the two tables, I do not need a separate loop for table 2 and I only need one row variable for both tables.

In my macro, I check the Id column of the two table and insert a partial row into table 2 when there is a mismatch.  So:

```
A        A
B        B
C        D
D
```

becomes:

```
A        A
B        B
C
D        D
```

You probably want to build a row in table 2 by moving values from the header columns of table 1 (columns A:B) to the header columns of table 2 (J:K) and setting the value column (L) to zero but I have not provided this code for you.

I would expect any VBA programmer to quickly become familiar with `For` loops etc. but inserting partial rows is not something I do every day so I do not have the necessary syntax at my fingertips.  I switched on the macro recorder, inserted a partial line, switched off the macro recorder and examined the code it created:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
' Macro recorded 14/10/2014 by Tony Dallimore
'

'
    Range("J7:L7").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
End Sub
```

This is syntactically correct VBA but not good VBA.  It is rarely good practice to select cells or ranges.  The two keys statements can be replaced by:

```
    Range("J7:L7").Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

`"J7:L7"` is just a string which I can build at run time:

```
    .Range(ColNewFirst & RowBothCrnt & ":" & ColNewLast & RowBothCrnt).Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

Above I have introduced all the elements of the macro below.  Come back with questions if necessary but the more you can decipher this code yourself, the faster you will develop.

```
' Look up this statement to read why its inclusion is a good idea
Option Explicit
Sub AlignRows()

  ' Using constants instead of literals has the following effects:
  '  * It takes a little longer to type your macro.
  '  * It makes your macro self-documenting.
  '  * If new header rows or data columns are added, amending the constants
  '    will fix the macro.
  Const ColExistId As String = "A"
  Const ColNewId As String = "J"
  Const ColNewFirst As String = "J"
  Const ColNewLast As String = "L"
  Const RowDataFirst As Long = 6

  Dim RowBothCrnt As Long
  Dim RowExistLast As Long

  ' I do not know the name of your worksheet.  Replace "Data" with your worksheet name
  With Worksheets("Data")

    RowExistLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, ColExistId).End(xlUp).Row

    For RowBothCrnt = RowDataFirst To RowExistLast
      If .Cells(RowBothCrnt, ColExistId).Value <> _
         .Cells(RowBothCrnt, ColNewId).Value Then
        .Range(ColNewFirst & RowBothCrnt & ":" & _
               ColNewLast & RowBothCrnt).Insert Shift:=xlDown
      End If
    Next

  End With

End Sub
```